# Why set "ansible_python_interpreter" conf option to '/usr/bin/python3'

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I want to use python 3.6 with Ansible on the managed nodes (controlling node can use whatever, I guess).

On its [official doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/python_3_support.html), it says to enable python 3.6 on managed nodes, I have to set the `ansible_python_interpreter` configuration option to `/usr/bin/python3`. This option is an `inventory option`. I know it is possible to set this inventory variable even with dynamic inventory, but I just don't want that much complexity going into setting a variable.

So I did not set this option, instead I:

1. Use `ec2_module` to automatically provision an aws ec2 ubuntu18.04 (which comes with python 3.6 at `/usr/bin/python3`) (I could also use `raw` module to install it if it's not present)
2. Use `raw` module to create a symlink from `/usr/bin/python` to `/usr/bin/python3`

I tried it and it seems as long as the `/usr/bin/python` is set to an acceptable version of python (`>= 2.7` or `>= 3.6`) then it should work...

**Question:** So what's the point of setting the ansible_python_interpreter configuration option to `/usr/bin/python3`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Question: So what's the point of setting the ansible_python_interpreter configuration option to /usr/bin/python3?

By default, Ansible will always use `/usr/bin/python` on the remote system. You set `ansible_python_interpreter` to provide a path to something that *isn't* `/usr/bin/python` if you want it to use that instead.  Sure, you can create a symlink instead, but:

- How is that any easier than setting an inventory variable?
- On many distributions, `/usr/bin/python` already exists and is Python 2 and is required by system tools.  Replacing it will break things.
- Even on systems that don't ship with Python 2 by default, by creating a symlink from `/usr/bin/python` to `/usr/bin/python3` you have potentially broken anything that expects `/usr/bin/python` to be Python 2. That might not bite you now but it might surprise you in the future.

Comment: The second and third points make sense, I don't think much about it probably because I haven't run into it. However, I've been searching for ways to use the `ansible_python_interpreter` dynamically during the play to no avails... I'd appreciate if you can provide me a link for that.

Comment: At a guess you should be able to modify the value of `ansible_python_interpreter` using something like `set_fact`, but if you've tried that and it didn't work it's probably worth posting a new question to show what you've tried.